# Java JSON converter "undefined for type" error

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jar

Using Eclipse, I’m converting data to JSON. I’ve downloaded the `json.jar` file and added it to my class path. I’ve imported these,

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

But when I try to use `.add`, `.toJSONString` and `.contains` I get errors like these,

```
The method add(String) is undefined for the type JSONArray
The method add(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONArray
The method toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject
```

Why is this happening? Here is the full code below.

```
   private JSONObject getJson(){

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        String forename = null;
        String surname = null;

        JSONArray nodes = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray links = new JSONArray();


        Map<Integer,Integer> sourceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> targetMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        int linkSourceActivity = -1;
        int linkTargetActivity = -1;
        String activity =null;
        int sourceId = -1;
        int targetId = -1;
        int nodeIndex = 0;
        int targetIndex = -1;
        JSONObject jsonLine = null;


        // Iterate over the Map of links
        for(Integer index : this.links.keySet()){

            // gather information needed for Json object
            Link link = this.links.get(index);
            // nodes need


            sourceId = link.getSourceId();
            targetId = link.getTargetId();


            forename = people.getValue(link.getSourceId()).getForenames();
            surname = people.getValue(link.getSourceId()).getSurname();

            linkSourceActivity = link.getSourceActivityCode();

            //If source node doesn't exist, create it
            if(!sourceMap.containsKey(sourceId)){

                // Create a node and add to array
                jsonLine = new JSONObject();
                jsonLine.put("name",forename+ " " +surname);
                jsonLine.put("group", linkSourceActivity);
                jsonLine.put("role", "Director");
                nodes.add(jsonLine);
                // add entry to map
                sourceMap.put(sourceId, nodeIndex);
                nodeIndex++;
            }

            forename = people.getValue(link.getTargetId()).getForenames();
            surname = people.getValue(link.getTargetId()).getSurname();
            linkTargetActivity = link.getTargetActivityCode();
            activity = link.getTargetActivity();
            targetIndex = (targetId * 0x1f1f1f1f) ^ linkTargetActivity;


            // If the target node doesn't exist, create it
            if(!targetMap.containsKey(targetIndex)){
                jsonLine = new JSONObject();
                jsonLine.put("name", forename+ " " +surname);
                jsonLine.put("group", linkTargetActivity);
                jsonLine.put("role", activity);
                nodes.add(jsonLine);

                // add entry to map
                targetMap.put(targetIndex, nodeIndex);
                nodeIndex++;
            }


            // links need
            // source (position in node array)
            // target (position in node array)

            int sourcePos = sourceMap.get(sourceId);
            int targetPos = targetMap.get(targetIndex);
            int value = link.getMultiplicity();

            // Build the array of play titles for this Link
            List<Integer> productionIds = link.getProductions();
            JSONArray playTitles = new JSONArray();
            int playId = -1;
            String playName = null;
            for (Integer Id : productionIds){
                playId = productions.getValue(Id).getPlayId();
                playName = plays.getValue(playId).getMainTitle();
                // don't include duplicate titles
                if(!playTitles.contains(playName)){
                    playTitles.add(plays.getValue(playId).getMainTitle());
                }
            }

            JSONObject linkLine = new JSONObject();
            linkLine.put("source", sourcePos);
            linkLine.put("target", targetPos);
            linkLine.put("value", value);
            linkLine.put("plays", playTitles);
            links.add(linkLine);

        } // end iterate over Links
        obj.put("nodes", nodes);
        obj.put("links", links);

        return obj;
    } // end getJson method

    // Method to write Json to a file
    public void writeJson(String path){
        try {

            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path);
            file.write(jsonLinks.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


} // end JsonOutput
```

Comment: Beacuse JsonArray does not have a function called add. refer http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using the wrong library, code works fine with JSONsimple ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `org.json.JSONArray` does not have a method `put(..)`. See the JavaDoc.

You could use [`public JSONArray put(java.lang.Object value)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#put%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: What about toJSONString() ?  I've changed it to toString() but don't understand why that won't work. and what about .contains?

Comment: @gbhrea Because [`JSONArray`](www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) does not have a method `toJSONString()`. What library are you using, what do you *think* you are using?

Comment: The [JSONObject] library does have a to JSONString ()method ?

Comment: `JSONObject` is not a library, it's a class. There is more than one library that provides a class `JSONObject`. Which do you think you are using? On what web site do you read about `toJSONString()`?

Comment: Was using the wrong library, code works fine with JSONsimple ! :)